# How to create enum from a SQL query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create an enum from distinct values of a column in PostgreSQL. Instead of creating an enum from all labels, I want to create it using a query to get all possible values of the type. I am expecting something like:

```
CREATE TYPE genre_type AS ENUM
   (select distinct genre from movies);
```

But I am not allowed to do this. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need an `enum` for this? Wouldn't a simple FK to a `genres` table work just as well?

Comment: @muistooshort It could be that the OP wants to have a constant enum, irrelevant of changes made into the table. FK is a good solution in most, but not all times.

Answer (score 9):

If genre types are in any way dynamic, i.e. you create new ones and rename old ones from time to time, or if you want to save additional information with every genre type, [@mu's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510687/how-to-create-enum-from-a-sql-query-in-postgresql#comment23703462_16510687) and [@Marcello's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511204/939860) would be worth considering - except you should just use type `text` instead of `varchar(20)` and consider `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for the FK constraint.

Other than that, here is the **recipe** you asked for:

```sql
DO
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('CREATE TYPE genre_type AS ENUM (%s)'
               , string_agg(DISTINCT quote_literal(genre), ', '))
   FROM   movies
   );
END 
$$;
```

You need dynamic SQL for that. The simple way is a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command (PostgreSQL 9.0+).
Make sure your strings are properly escaped with `quote_literal()`.
I aggregate the string with [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) (PostgreSQL 9.0+).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do that *by design*.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html

> Enumerated (enum) types are data types that comprise a static, ordered
>   set of values.

The "DISTINCT" keyword in your SELECT clause makes me think your schema is not fully normalized.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE movies(
    ...
    genre VARCHAR(20)
    ...
);

SELECT DISTINCT genre FROM movies;
```

Should become:

```
CREATE TABLE genres(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE movies (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    genre INTEGER REFERENCES genres(id)
);

SELECT name FROM genres;
```

Answer (score 1):

A trivial approach would be to execute the `SELECT` in a client and then copy the names from it.

I think that is about everything you can do. If you look at the documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtype.html you will notice that there is written `CREATE TYPE name AS ENUM ( [ 'label' [, ... ] ] )` so what is not there is the keyword `expression`. That means that after `ENUM` there may not be an expression but only a list of labels.

You may want to follow @muistooshort's advice and create a genres table (that you can fill with an `INSERT ... SELECT ...`) and then create a `foreign key` to that table.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in pgsql. Here's inline code to do it:

```
DO $$
  DECLARE temp text;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO temp string_agg(DISTINCT quote_literal(genre),',') FROM movies;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE foo AS ENUM ('||temp||')';
END$$;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/29cf1/6)

Comment: `DISTINCT` outside of `string_agg()` is probably a typo?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter A little more than a typo, I forgot about it and then just put it somewhere when I saw op used it. Thanks.